# C# System.Data.Sqlite ignores parameter size when inserting binary data

Tags: c#, memory-management, system.data.sqlite

I'm inserting a series of BLOB values into an SQLite database using System.Data.SQLite and .NET Framework 3.5.

In order to avoid unnecessary memory allocations, I've tried to utilize the same buffer (`byte[]`) or, as another option, to pass the external buffer received from MemoryStream.GetBuffer() (as in the example below).

The problem is that SQLiteParameter ignores the Size (of the parameter) and uses the full length of the passed array instead.

The size of the data is 4-16KB, but the library always saves 128KB to DB (the default allocation size of MemoryStream):

```cs
public void SaveBlobNoAllocations(ulong id, MemoryStream data)
{
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("...", _db))
    {
        var param = command.CreateParameter();

        param.DbType = DbType.Binary;
        param.ParameterName = "@data";
        param.Value = data.GetBuffer();
        param.Size = (int)data.Length;  // <-- 

        // data.Length is 4767
        // data.GetBuffer().Length is 131072
        // 131072 bytes will be written to DB

        _ = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

To write the correct amount of bytes to the DB I have to allocate a new array, copy data to that array, and then bind it as a parameter:

```cs
public void SaveBlobWithAllocations(ulong id, MemoryStream data)
{
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("...", _db))
    {
        var byteArray = new byte[data.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data.GetBuffer(), 0, byteArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
        command.Parameters.Add("@data", DbType.Binary, byteArray.Length).Value = byteArray;
        _ = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My question is how to avoid unnecessary memory allocations for this particular case? It looks like the Size parameter was designed exactly for this purpose.

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice!

Comment: That is not, in fact, what `Size` is intended for, that just specifies the declared size of the type. And since SQLite uses dynamic typing, it would make little sense for it to actually treat that size rigidly (other DB systems could choose to truncate the value, giving your desired result, or more likely they'd give an error that the value *would* be truncated).

Comment: If the driver supports streaming, you can simply pass in a `Stream` directly as the `Value`. You can use the `MemoryStream` constructor that takes an array and a size to "slice" an existing buffer that way, without reallocation. The `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` driver instead offers a dedicated [`SqliteBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/blob-io) class for this; I don't know what `System.Data.SQLite` supports, since its docs don't appear to be available in an open format (`chm` does not count).

Comment: @JeroenMostert  interestingly enough in `SqlParameterCollection.Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)`  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlparametercollection-add(system-string-system-data-sqldbtype-system-int32)) remarks (not the `SqliteParameterCollection` though) following is stated -  _"This overload is useful when you are adding a parameter of a variable-length data type such as `varchar` or `binary`."_

Comment: @GuruStron: Sure, it *is* useful, in that it actually signals the data type to the database. For example, if the engine is SQL Server, it is a very good idea to specify the correct size for the parameter, since this prevents polluting the query cache -- if the size is not specified explicitly, it's just going to be inferred from the actual length of your value, but you may then end up with one plan per invocation instead of one plan per query, as is the intent. However, the exact way the size is treated depends on both your engine and the driver (the above is not relevant for SQLite).

Comment: Another way the size is useful is to prevent silent truncations -- for example, trying to stuff an overlong value in a parameter that's shorter can be caught on the client side before the command is even transmitted, whereas the server side may instead accept overlong values but silently truncate them on conversion (again, whether this is actually checked and what actually happens depends on the driver and the engine). None of this unfortunately guarantees the behavior the OP desires (slicing without reallocating).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, @GuruStron, thank you for your helpful discussion! I have created a small test and found that `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` works as I expected, i.e. it uses `Size` to limit data passed to DB. However, on the other hand, couldn't write a stream to `SqliteBlob` so far. Another interesting thing I found is that for the scenario described in my question `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` with no allocations works 2 times faster than `System.Data.SQLite` when copying data to a temp array. I've tested both libraries with a help of `BenchmarkDotNet` using .NET6.0.

Comment: My conclusion is to continue using `System.Data.SQLite` with allocations in the legacy .NET Framework 3.5 project, but switch to `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` for new projects. Thank you again for helping me to figure this out, it wasn't obvious which library to use!